# Inner join a SQL Pivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I cant seem to inner join to a teachers table in order to get the first and surname.

```
select * 
from BookingDays bd
inner join Teachers t 
  on t.ID = bd.TeacherID
pivot 
(
  max (bd.BookingDuration) 
  for bd.DayText in ([MONDAY], [TUESDAY], [WEDNESDAY], [THURSDAY], [FRIDAY])
) as MaxBookingDays
where bd.BookingDate >= (SELECT DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,GETDATE()), 0)) and   
   bd.BookingDate <= (SELECT DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,GETDATE()), 6)) '
```

The error message I get is -

```
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The column 'ID' was specified multiple times for 'MaxBookingDays'.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The multi-part identifier "bd.BookingDate" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The multi-part identifier "bd.BookingDate" could not be bound.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error below is because you are not specifying your columns:

> *Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 3*
>
> *The column 'ID' was specified multiple times for 'MaxBookingDays'.*

So I would change your query slightly to something like this:

```
select *
from
(
  -- don't use select *, call out your fields
  -- and use a sub-query with your WHERE inside the subquery
  select bd.BookingDuration, bd.Otherfields, t.Fields
  from BookingDays bd
  inner join Teachers t 
    on t.ID = bd.TeacherID
  where bd.BookingDate >= (SELECT DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,GETDATE()), 0)) and   
    bd.BookingDate <= (SELECT DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,GETDATE()), 6))
) src
pivot 
(
  max (BookingDuration) 
  for DayText in ([MONDAY], [TUESDAY], [WEDNESDAY],[THURSDAY], [FRIDAY])
) as MaxBookingDays
```