# Pivot with join

Tags: sql, join, syntax, pivot

```
select 'Total' as PPT_TMT,    
[Lastname1], [Lastname2], [Lastname3], [Lastname4], [Lastname5]    
from    
     (   
     select u.Lastname, o.PriceTotal, o.MarginTotal   
     from dbo.Orders o join dbo.[User] u on o.UserID = u.UserID  
     where UserID in (393, 455, 496, 530, 531)  
     and CompletedDate > dateadd(m, -1, GETDATE())  
     ) AS SourceCode  
PIVOT  
(  
     SUM(SUM(o.PriceTotal) - SUM(o.MarginTotal))   
     FOR Lastname IN ([Lastname1], [Lastname2], [Lastname3], [Lastname4], [Lastname5])  
) AS Gain;
```

This query won't seem to run for me. Same syntax error every time.

"Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near '('."

Here are a couple resources I've referenced:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

[Inner join a SQL Pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878595/inner-join-a-sql-pivot-table)

Let me know if you have any ideas!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `SUM(SUM(X) - SUM(Y))`, this could be simplified as `SUM(X) - SUM(Y)`.  However, I don't believe `PIVOT` supports even such a simple expression; you need to do so in your inner query.